# angular: how can i iterate over founded items on my page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, loops, search

I implemented two pipes. One pipe for highlighting and one for searching items on my array.
But i want also iterate over the founded items by e.g. clicking enter.
Has anyone an idea ??

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedTerm"> <br>
    <div class="smoothie">
<div class="scroller" class="textarea" *ngFor="let file of getFileAnalyze | search: searchedTerm"  [style.color]="colors[file.fileCategory]">
  <span [innerHTML]="file.date | highlight: searchedTerm"></span>  <span [innerHTML]="file.content | highlight: searchedTerm"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

**search.pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!list) { return []; }
    if (!searchText) { return list; }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return list.filter( item => {
          return item.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        });
      }
}
```

**highlight.pipe**

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight'
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(list: any, searchText: string): SafeHtml {

    if (!list) { return []; }
    if (!searchText) { return list; }

    const value = list.replace(
      searchText, `<span style='background-color:yellow'>${searchText}</span>` );

    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "clicking enter" ?? Do you mean key pres 'enter'?

Comment: yes exactly :) It can be also by clicking on a button. Do you have an idea or an example ?